# An error in the Damour-Ruffini method for derivation of Hawking radiations?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I was reading [this document, page 5](http://pagesperso.ihes.fr/%7Edamour/Articles/these4.pdf) (*Black-Hole evaporation in the Klein-Sauter-Heisenberg-Euler formalism*, T. Damour, R. Ruffini), and the keys of the Damour-Ruffini method exposed here are :

1. Expressing the field with the Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates
2. Taking the prescription $r-r_+=(r_+-r)e^{-i\pi}$ when $r<r_+$

Now, to find the Hawking radiations one uses the ratio between the modulus squared of the field outside and inside the horizon. As an example [this document](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.00462) (*Analytic solutions in the dyon black hole with a cosmic string: scalar fields, Hawking radiation and energy flux*, H. S. Vieira, V. B. Bezerra, and G. V. Silva) uses the Damour-Ruffini method page 17, and the coefficient I am talking about is $\Gamma_+$, Eq. 102.

I have a big problem with this derivation. Indeed in the latter article the following expressions are used:
\begin{align}
\Psi_\text{out} (r>r_+) &= e^{-i\omega v}(r-r_+)^{\frac{i}{\kappa_+}(\omega-\omega_{0,b})}
\\
\Psi_\text{out} (r<r_+) &= e^{-i\omega v}(r_+-r)^{\frac{i}{\kappa_+}(\omega-\omega_{0,b})}e^{\frac{\pi}{\kappa_+}(\omega-\omega_{0,b})}
\end{align}
Where $r_+$ is the radius of the horizon, $v$ is $t+r_\ast$ ($r_\ast$ the tortoise coordinate), and $\kappa_+$ is the surface gravity on the horizon. Then, they claim that:
\begin{equation}
\Gamma_+=\left| \frac{\Psi_\text{out} (r>r_+)}{\Psi_\text{out} (r<r_+)} \right|^2=e^{-\frac{2\pi}{\kappa_+}(\omega-\omega_{0,b})}
\end{equation}
But, by definition, $v$ involves $\ln(r-r_+)$ and then for $r<r_+$ one has $v_{r<r_+}=v_{r>r_+}-i\pi$. It seems to me that the authors neglect this fact and just simplify the $e^{-i\omega v}$ to obtain $\Gamma_+$. If one take into account the behaviors of $v$ near the horizon then one has:
\begin{equation}
\Gamma_+=\left| \frac{e^{-i\omega v_{r>r_+}}(r-r_+)^{\frac{i}{\kappa_+}(\omega-\omega_{0,b})}}{e^{-i\omega v_{r<r_+}}(r_+-r)^{\frac{i}{\kappa_+}(\omega-\omega_{0,b})}e^{\frac{\pi}{\kappa_+}(\omega-\omega_{0,b})}} \right|^2=e^{-\frac{\pi}{\kappa_+}(\omega-\omega_{0,b})}
\end{equation}
Provided that $\omega v=\omega t+\frac{\omega-\omega_{0,b}}{2\kappa_+}\ln(r-r_+)$. This result is the same if one uses the usual coordinates $t$ and $r$ instead of the Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates.

Where am I wrong? It seems to me that the result should not depend on the coordinate system used and it is the case in my derivation, but the authors use the same simplification of $e^{-i\omega v}$ several times, and in other articles, so I might be wrong, but I can't see how to reconcile my derivation and theirs.

Comment: Did you find a resolution to your problem ? I am not particularly fan of Damour Ruffini method because they use negative norm states.  And I had hard time following their argument, especially caption in the Fig.1 (in their paper) confused me. The boundary condition they pick appear to have outgoing solution at the horizon which seem to be at odd with other treatments, in which there is only ingoing solution at the horizon cf [arXiv:hep-th/9702015]

Comment: @user91411 I had to send an e-mail to H. S. Vieira in order to find a solution to this problem and this solution is simply "since $v$ and $r-r_+$ are independent variables in this coordinate system, we don't have to use the prescription for $v$" (where the prescription I'm talking about is my point $2.$).

Comment: Perhaps there is a typo in those expressions. $f_{\text{out}}$ and $f_{\text{in}}$ can be written in terms of one another but the factor in front $e^{-i \omega v}$ needs to be replaced by $e^{-i \omega t}$